# Google maps call with Ajax, why do I have to click twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am currently plotting markers on google maps using ajax (Using a modified version of the overlapping spiderfy script (https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier).

This all works and I then need to load the ajax on the click of my search button. When I click the button once it does not load, a second click however it does. What do I need to alter in this script to get this to work please?

```
<script>
             function loadMapData()
          {

         var markers = [];

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "maps2.php",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        markers.push({
                            lon: data[i].long,
                            lat: data[i].lat,
                            h: data[i].city,
                            d: data[i].post_title
                        });
                    }

                    window.mapData = markers;
                }
        });

        var gm = google.maps;
            var map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                center: new gm.LatLng(50.806748, -1.079407), zoom: 12, // whatevs: fitBounds will override
                scrollwheel: false
            });
            var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();
            var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,
                    {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true});

            var usualColor = 'eebb22';
            var spiderfiedColor = 'ffee22';
            var iconWithColor = function (color) {
                return 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|+|' +
                        color + '|000000|ffff00';
            }
            var shadow = new gm.MarkerImage(
                    'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
                    new gm.Size(37, 34), // size   - for sprite clipping
                    new gm.Point(0, 0), // origin - ditto
                    new gm.Point(10, 34)  // anchor - where to meet map location
                    );

            oms.addListener('click', function (marker) {
                iw.setContent(marker.desc);
                iw.open(map, marker);
            });
            oms.addListener('spiderfy', function (markers) {
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
                    markers[i].setShadow(null);
                }
                iw.close();
            });
            oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function (markers) {
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
                    markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
                }
            });

            var bounds = new gm.LatLngBounds();


            for (var i = 0; i < window.mapData.length; i++) {
                var datum = window.mapData[i];
                var loc = new gm.LatLng(datum.lat, datum.lon);
                bounds.extend(loc);
                var marker = new gm.Marker({
                    position: loc,
                    title: datum.h,
                    map: map,
                    icon: iconWithColor(usualColor),
                    shadow: shadow
                });
                marker.desc = datum.d;
                oms.addMarker(marker);
            }
            //map.fitBounds(bounds);

            // for debugging/exploratory use in console
            window.map = map;
            window.oms = oms;





    }

   </script>

 <div class="col-md-3"><input type="button" value="Search" class="loadAjaxMap" /></div>


<script>
  $( ".loadAjaxMap" ).click(function() {
   loadMapData();
 });
</script>


    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I think what's happening is that `ajax` isn't finished loading (populating) markers but you already overlaying them on the map. Ajax is asynchonous, so the rest of the code will continue execution without waiting on ajax to finish. Try setting `async:false` for your ajax call and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XmlHttpRequest is asynchronous. You need to use the data in the callback function when it is available.

```
function loadMapData()
{
  var markers = [];
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "maps2.php",
     success: function(data)
     {
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
       {
         markers.push({
           lon: data[i].long,
           lat: data[i].lat,
           h: data[i].city,
           d: data[i].post_title
         });
       }
       window.mapData = markers;
      var gm = google.maps;
      var map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
          center: new gm.LatLng(50.806748, -1.079407), zoom: 12, // whatevs: fitBounds will override
          scrollwheel: false
      });
      var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();
      var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,
                {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true});

      var usualColor = 'eebb22';
      var spiderfiedColor = 'ffee22';
      var iconWithColor = function (color) {
          return 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|+|' +
          color + '|000000|ffff00';
      }
      var shadow = new gm.MarkerImage(
              'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
              new gm.Size(37, 34), // size   - for sprite clipping
              new gm.Point(0, 0), // origin - ditto
              new gm.Point(10, 34)  // anchor - where to meet map location
              );
       oms.addListener('click', function (marker) {
          iw.setContent(marker.desc);
          iw.open(map, marker);
      });
      oms.addListener('spiderfy', function (markers) {
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
             markers[i].setShadow(null);
         }
         iw.close();
      });
      oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function (markers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
             markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
        }
      });
      var bounds = new gm.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < window.mapData.length; i++) {
          var datum = window.mapData[i];
          var loc = new gm.LatLng(datum.lat, datum.lon);
          bounds.extend(loc);
          var marker = new gm.Marker({
              position: loc,
              title: datum.h,
              map: map,
              icon: iconWithColor(usualColor),
              shadow: shadow
          });
          marker.desc = datum.d;
          oms.addMarker(marker);
      }
      //map.fitBounds(bounds);
      // for debugging/exploratory use in console
      window.map = map;
      window.oms = oms;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just calling the `loadMapData()` function `onClick` and removing your second script altogether:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" class="loadAjaxMap" onClick="loadMapData();" />
```